# The Unforgivable Sin

Tags: soteriology, sin, pneumatology, unforgivable-sin

I have a question that I need answered,  I am fearfully worried for my salvation!.

Some time ago I went through some spiritual problems - One such thing is that I started reading about the 'Unforgivable Sin'.  I felt I had comitted it!.

I started reading about it and asking questions,  I got two responses - 
1) It was a Demon - making me believe I had done it.
2) It was the Holy Spirit - making me realize my sin and need for repentance hence the worry.

I pondered for weeks over this e.g. How can people give two opposing responses.  Then one day under my breath while working it out I said 'The Holy Spirit is Like a D****'

I didn't think anything of it at the time as I was basing this statement on a vauge view of the Holy Spirit and Demons.

I am worried that God will have taken this the wrong way - In my confusion I said this - That being said I never ever, ever meant it in the connotation that the Holy Spirit is evil.

The statement was mearly me working out how to tell them apart.  E.g. If some christians said number 1 and others number 2 then my reasoning is there must be some aspects that are undisernable.

We are even told to Test the Spirits which would mean comparing them and even finding Similaries otherwise we would not need to test them in the first place.

I am fearfully worried God will not understand what I mean?  Can someone tell me weather I have committed this or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't answer questions like this. Mostly because we don't trust ourselves. With questions like yours we want you to go talk to someone in real life. Your pastor or priest, a trusted friend, or someone in your church that you trust.

It's not that we don't want to help, but on the contrary, we don't feel that it's in anyone's best interest to try to do so on this site.  For more info, please see this post:  [Pastoral Advice Questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions)

Comment: You wrote "I am worried that God will have taken this the wrong way" and "I am fearfully worried that God will not understand what I mean?" You need not have these worries.  God is omniscient; He knows exactly what you mean, no matter how (or even whether) you expressed it in words.

Answer (score 1):

While I will not attempt to provide you with advice or counsel in helping you get past your current situation, I will be so bold as to state, based on my understanding of the truth of God's word, that there is only one unforgiveable sin, and that is unbelief, (which according to your question is not the issue with which you seem to be struggling).  The good news, however, is that even unbelief can be forgiven if we truly repent and believe before it's too late (in other words, before we die)!

Clearly, when the unbelievers in Jesus' day attributed to Satan the works Jesus performed in the power of the Holy Spirit, their sin, if not repented of, would not have been forgivable. On the other hand, repented of, their sin would be forgiven, as would any and all of their other sins.

John's first letter tells us that the blood of Jesus Christ cleanses us of all unrighteousness (1:9); not some, not most, but *all*.  Interestingly, our sins are not what condemn us; unbelief is what condemns us. Christ has already done what was necessary to make the forgiveness of our sins a reality through His death on the cross, where God imputed our sins to Jesus. When we believe this fact, God then imputes Jesus' righteousness to us. In other words, forgiveness is possible only through our belief that His sacrificial death on the cross was for the forgiveness of our sins.

> John 3:18, NIV: "Whoever believes in him is not condemned, but whoever does not believe stands condemned already because he has not believed in the name of God's one and only Son."
>
> John 3:36 NAS: "He who believes in the Son has eternal life ; but he who does not obey the Son will not see life, but the wrath of God abides on him."

Notice what Jesus says about the link between unbelief and condemnation. According to Him, not to believe in God's one and only Son is what ultimately condemns us. Again, sin is not what condemns us but unbelief is.  Moreover, the refusal to believe in the Son means not only will we not see life (abundant life now and eternal life both now and later), but God will continue being righteously angry with us until we do believe.

From what I'm hearing from you, it is not unbelief that is the cause of your present quandary, it's the vague uneasiness that you've committed a sin that is not forgivable. As I have taken pains to point out, however, the only unforgivable sin is unbelief. When we commit any sin other than that, God graciously forgives us when we simply confess to Him we've blown it. We then can pick ourselves up, dust ourselves off, and move forward, confident that nothing can separate us from the love of God that is in Christ Jesus (Romans 8:35-39).